# Get custom domain name to work with app engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a domain name purchased via google domains. I want to point it to my app engine instance. In the "custom domains" settings tab in the app engine console, I have the following:

[image]

I want both the "bare" and "www" flavors to point to my app engine instance:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

I'm not sure which option to use for step #2 to get that to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd be following the [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) procedure, with focus on section 4:

> ```
> 4. Continue to the next step the Add new custom domain form, selecting the custom domain you want to point to your App Engine app:
>
>   a. Refresh the console domain page so it will list the domains properly.
>   b. If you want to use a subdomain, such as www, use the second option (http://www.example.com).
>   c. If you want to use a naked domain, use the first option to specify a naked domain (such as http://example.com).
>   d. Click Add to create the desired mapping.
> ```

You need to specifically add **both** the naked domain and the `www` subdomain, explicitly, by running the entire section 4 twice, once selecting 4c and once selecting 4b, respectively.

To do that at step #2 (in the `Add a custom domain` screen illustrated in your image) you first select the 1st radiobutton, for `http://example.com` and click `Add`. Unfortunately you don't see this addition displayed anywhere in the developer console (AFAIK). When the custom domain config was done through Google Apps the naked domain was visible explicitly, but that's no longer available.

Then come back at the `Add a custom domain` screen and at step #2 select the 2nd radiobutton, fill in `www` in the text input area (if needed), select `example.com` from the dropdown list (if needed) and click `Add`. This adddition should cause a new entry to be listed in the `Custom Domain` main screen (the parent screen), with a `www.example.com` **Custom domain name** and a `www` **Alias**.

This should be all (it may take a while for the DNS changes to propagate to your machine so that you can verify the effects, the doc mentions up to 24h).