# Mapping subdomain to a service in Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain, google-domain-api

I have a Google App Engine project with following yaml file

```
handlers:
- url: /web/.*
  script: web_server.app

- url: /api/.*
  script: rest_server.app
```

How do I make sure subdomain, of a domain I own, be served by rest_server.app script.

Example: If I own example.com

I want `example.com` to be served by `web_server.app`, and `api.example.com` to be served by `rest_server.app`

Is it possible to do that using Google App Engine.

Example:

```
handlers:
- url: example.com/.*
  script: web_server.app
- url: api.example.com/.*
  script: rest_server.app
```

Comment: Just a clarification, your 2 scripts are not actually GAE **services** (as mentioned in the post's title), they're just different **scripts** in your app's single/`default` GAE service. You'll see the difference from my answer below - the solution *is* based on GAE services. I just noticed the potential confusing inconsistency :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Request routing in the `app.yaml` can not be used to route based on the URL's domain name, see the `url` table row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element) doc section.

Because of that you can't really have a single module/service serving your app while simultaneously stripping the filepath portion of the URL you're currently used in your handlers' `url` configs for routing requests to one script or the other.

You can obtain what you desire by splitting your app into 2 separate [services/modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#services_the_building_blocks_of_app_engine), each handling one script. One of the modules has to be the default module, I'd make the `web` one the default.
A [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dispatchref) file would be used to route requests to their respective modules based on the URL hostname.

The `web.yaml` file would contain:

```
module: default

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: web_server.app
```

The `rest.yaml` file would contain:

```
module: rest

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: rest_server.app
```

In the `dispatch.yaml` file you only need routes for the non-default module(s), requests matching no routes are by default routed to the defaut module:

```
- url: "api.example.com/*"
  module: rest
```

You can find a more complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111170/4495081

You'd then map both your `example.com` **naked domain** and `api.example.com` **subdomain** to your app. Follow the [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) procedure, paying extra attention to the sections which are slightly different when configuring a naked domain vs a subdomain. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36317462/4495081

There is one **problem**, tho - `dispatch.yaml` routing based on hostnames doesn't work with the local development server, the requests destined for the `rest` module would actually go to the `default` module.

A simpler workaround would be to direct the `rest` module clients to the actual localhost:PORT URL where the local devserver's `rest` module listens (displayed in the terminal at dev server startup), instead.

This *might* not be possible in all cases or for all apps. For example it's an issue if the app makes cross-module requests with auto-generated URLs.

In such cases, to work around it you can temporarily insert a small path portion in the `rest.yaml` URL, only during testing on the local dev server the `rest` module (you'd need matching changes on the client side and/or the cross-module URL generation logic):

```
module: rest

handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: rest_server.app
```

And then you can add a `dispatch.yaml` rule that is not host-based and would also with the local dev server. This can be left in there permanently, it doesn't hurt if/when deployed in production when the temporary `rest.yaml` change is reversed:

```
- url: "api.example.com/*"
  module: rest
- url: "*/api/*"
  module: rest
```

Comment: How do I deploy with this new structure. I tried `gcloud app delpoy web.yaml rest.yaml`, but it didn't work. Both naked domain and the api.* subdomian are served by web.yaml.

Now, I am trying to deploy using the following command `gcloud app deploy web.yaml rest.yaml dispatch.yaml`. And it takes long time and there is no progress after this log statement.

INFO: Uploading [/server/src/dispatch.yaml] to [899bc6aeea3e3615e45e54eefe593acf2065b6b3]

Comment: Looks like there were unnecessary spaces in my dispatch.yaml that were causing the issue of `gcloud app deploy` getting stuck while uploading dispatch.yaml. Such a weird issue ( i was able to reproduce it to make sure it was the spaces that were causing the issue).

`gcloud app deploy web.yaml rest.yaml dispatch.yaml` worked!! Thanks!!!

Comment: i'm wondering if dispatch.yaml works with appengine flex, about to find out I guess

Comment: @the0ther yes, `dispatch.yaml` is an app-level config, shared by all app's services while the choice of the flex vs standard environment is a service-level config (an app can mix services with different languages and environments). In fact it's specified for the flex environment as well: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file

Comment: i think 5 minutes after i posed the question here, i searched and landed on documentation for dispatch.yaml under the flex URL. thanks just the same!