# How to Deploy 2 apps using on the same domain?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, deployment, devops

I've created 2 different React projects and looking to deploy with Google App Engine on the same domain. I have project 1 already deployed up and live:

Project 1 - website (React only)

www.mywebsite.com

Project 2 - login services and dashboard features (React and Node.js) and begins at:

www.mywebsite.com/login

Project 2 is a beta test which may or may not be successful. Can I create a CNAME of www.mywebsite.com/login and point my project here? Is there a best practice to handle domains like this?

Comment: I think you should use [Mapping Custom Domains App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains). Here is also a related SO question [How to bind one domain/subdomain per service in the Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364774/how-to-bind-one-domain-subdomain-per-service-in-the-google-app-engine/50374106)

Answer (score 0):

You can't point DNS records to subdomains [(reference)](https://serverfault.com/questions/47175/can-a-cname-dns-record-point-to-a-subdirectory)

This kind of scenario would be possible configuring a traditional web server and having both apps hosted in it. I am not aware of a way to achieve this behavior in App Engine.