# GCP app engine flex not maping other services to subfolder

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have deployed a project on gcp app engine flex.
I have created the dispatch.yaml file and updated but my urls not working like i needed.
I got three versions running.

```
api-dot-site-appspot.com (service : api)
backend-dot-site-appspot.com ( service backend)
site-appspot.com (service : default)
i have added the custom doamin in gcp abc.com
```

all three application in laravel. and all flex urls working fine like  api-dot-site-appspot.com . but with custom domain if i open like abc.com/api/  it gives 404

so main domain is abc.com

```
abc.com should open site-appspot.com
abc.com/backend should open backend-dot-site-appspot.com
abc.com/api should open api-dot-site-appspot.com
```

so please apply if you have expertise on it.

below dispatch.yaml file i deployed

```
  dispatch:
  # Send all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
  #- url: "*/product/*"
   # service: default
  # Send all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
  - url: "*/dashboard/*"
    service: dashboard

  # Send all work to the one static backend.
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: api
```

Comment: Did you map the domain and each subdomain to the respective service in the GAE custom domain settings? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283743/get-custom-domain-name-to-work-with-app-engine-instance/36317462#36317462

Comment: In your dispatch, there isn't backend but dashboard? Is that the issue?